# Saving GCM regId in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on GCM Demo application and i am trying to store the registration Id from GCM server in mysql Database. It is stored in list in Datastore in the example. I have following code in RegisterServlet in the server side for the registration but there is no registration registered in the database. I really need your help please!

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
  throws ServletException {
String regId = getParameter(req, PARAMETER_REG_ID);

try {
//Load the Driver for connection
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
//Get a connection to the particular database
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/GCMFINAL", "root", "root");

PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement("insert into GCM(ID)values("+regId +")");
pstmt.execute();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
setSuccess(resp);
```

}

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you might be having an SQL syntax problem here:

```
"insert into GCM(regId)values("+regId +")"
```

Try adding spaces like this:

```
"insert into GCM (regId) values ("+regId +")"
```

Comment: Mike, Can you think of any other possibilities while i am trying this one.

Comment: @TseringYangzom Well what debugging have you done? What errors are you getting? Surely you can narrow down the problem to a few problematic lines of code where things are not happening as you expect.

Comment: @Mark, the thing is GCM does list registration of regId whereas my application does database registration. I am not getting any error but the regId is not there in database table.

Comment: Please anyone help me with the problem?